# Getting Error while Building Electron Application

Tags: reactjs, electron, electron-builder, electron-packager

I have created an UI using ReactJS and embedded the electron into that. I can run my React UI as a Desktop App using electron.

Now, I am facing an issue creating builder using electron-packager.

Below is the error: `rcedit.exe failed with exit code 1. Fatal error: Unable to commit changes`

However, I can see the created package in the "Temp" folder under "electron-package" folder still it throws the above error. Also, I have tried running executable from the Temp folder, it opens desktop app (still there are few errors but they are related to code - I am not worry about this errors).

ElectronJS - https://www.electronjs.org/

It would be great if someone help me on this.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By degrading Electron version from latest to [v10.1.6](https://www.electronjs.org/releases/stable?version=10&page=2#10.1.6), it got resolved.